# Accessing the main thread in a TKinter script?

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, tkinter

I think understand why I am receiving the following error `TclStackFree: incorrect freePtr. Call out of sequence?` but I am not sure how to fix the problem.

### Summary of my Script

My `Python`, `TKinter` script consists of three active threads. The main thread and two child threads. One of the child threads is responsible for listening for UDP messages and the other is responsible for graphing the data (using `Matplotlib`) that is received.To my best understanding, the problem is that I am trying to access the gui from the two child threads at the same time. For example, I may be receiving UDP messages and trying to display them on the gui while trying to graph previously received data. This is not uncommon because of the rate at which I am receiving UDP packets (up to 10,000 per second).

### Code

The two child threads are spawned using -

```
thread.start_new_thread(self.function, ())
```

**UDP Listener Thread**

```
def Listen(self):
    if self.udpClient.IsConnected():
        while True:
            #Listen for messages
            data = self.udpClient.listen(1024)
            #Add the data to the gui
            self.AddNewData(data)
            if self.disconnectFlag:
                break

def AddNewData(self, data):
    self.listbox.insert(END, data)
    receivedData.append(data)
```

**Graph Thread**

```
def UpdateGraph(self):
    while True:
        if readyToGraph:
            self.plot.clear()
            self.plot.hexbin(data[0], data[1], bins = "log", extent = self.extent)
            self.canvas.draw()

EDIT: 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = TK()
    gui = MainWindow(root, "Receiver")
    root.mainloop()
```

Like I said, I think the problem is that sometimes the Listener thread is attempting to add the data to the listbox at the same time that the graph thread trys to update the graph.

### I Have Tried...

Using `root.after_idle(...)` before attempting to modify the GUI but this just locks up the main thread. Example: `self.listbox.insert(END, data)` -> `root.after_idle(self.listbox.insert, END, data)` (I also called `root.after_idle` before `self.plot.clear()`, `self.plot.hexbin(...)`, and `self.canvas.draq()`)

I have also looked into `threading.condition` and `queue.queue` as suggested *[here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2011-February/002776.html)* but I couldn't find much information about either. (So I haven't really tried either solution)

### Question

How can I access the gui from the child threads without locking it up or causing the error stated above?

Comment: 90% sure you have to do your plotting on the main thread.

Comment: @tcaswell By calling `root.after_idle`? (By `root` I mean `TK`, sorry, I meant to specify that in the question)

Comment: also, don't import `pyplot` if you are embedding (I can't tell if you are).  Also don't use `plot` for names, it doesn't _technically_ clash with `plot()`, but it makes your code really hard to read.

Comment: I don't have much experience with tk and threading, but with QT you can not call any of the plotting functions from a worker thread.  I assume TK has some sort of call back or timer to tell the main thread to look at the data from the reader thread when it is ready

Comment: If I don't worry about adding the data to the listbox and just graph the data then everything works just fine. So that makes me think that I can graph without being in the main thread..

Comment: just because it does not blow up in one case does not mean it is safe, it means that one case happens to not blow up ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to what was discussed on the tkinter-discuss mailing list:
 https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2013-November/thread.html

This is the essence:

> Hi,
>
> afaik the after() / after_idle() calls are not thread safe!
>
> On my research leading to the code Andreas provide I found the
>   event_generate() method the only threadsafe way to invoke the tk
>   thread without letting it poll something. (As mentioned by Guido and
>   seen on other pages everyone else seems to poll... why?)
>
> brgds,
>
> -- Jan

Comment: So I'm not exactly sure how to implement this. Do you know how to use event_generate?