# Python Text Effects

Tags: python, animation, effects

I'm new to the Python world and I need a little help.

I want to create an application that displays a text message, and I need this text to have animation like fade in, text sweep, etc.

I was wondering if you guys can recommend me a couple of libraries or some code examples to achive this.

Thanks a lot

Edit 1: I Want to do this in a Window im Using Tkinter

Comment: Do you want to do this in the console? That's going to be hard... But if it's not the case, you can have a look at PyGame or Tkinter

Comment: No, I want to do this in a Window with Tkinter I know how to use the tkinter widgets, you have mentioned PyGame I gonna read about that.

Comment: Oh... I've never really used Tkinter before. Maybe have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319059/embedding-a-pygame-window-into-a-tkinter-or-wxpython-frame) to use both of them

Comment: "I want animation effects" is too vague. The answer really depends on which effects you specifically want. For example, tkinter supports fading text in and out, and moving it across the screen, but it doesn't support effects like flipping the text, bursting into confetti, etc. Your first step should be to work through a Tkinter tutorial and/or experiment with the widgets that support text, and then come back and ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

this sites may help you

1) http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml

2) https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/

3) https://inventwithpython.com/chapter17.html

4) https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7FC4E665CEAACD5E