# I'm embedding a pygame window into Tkinter, how do I manipulate the pygame window?

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame, embed

So I'm making a game in pygame, and I want to use tkinter as well. I embedded a pygame window into a tkinter window, but I can't seem to do anything with it.

For context, here is the full code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import os
import platform
import pygame

class window(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()  # Main window
        self.root.title("SquareScape")
        self.root.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\17_es\PycharmProjects\square_puzzle\images\icon.ico')
        self.root.configure(background='#9b9b9b')

        # Large Frame
        self.win_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, width=670, height=520, highlightbackground='#595959', highlightthickness=2)

        # menu (left side)
        self.menu = tk.Frame(self.win_frame, width=150, height=516, highlightbackground='#595959', highlightthickness=2)
        self.menu_label = tk.Label(self.menu, text="Settings", bg='#8a8a8a', font=("Courier", "16", "bold roman"))
        self.mute = tk.Button(self.menu, text="XXXX", font="Courier", bg='#bcbcbc', activebackground='#cdcdcd')

        # pygame
        self.pygame_frame = tk.Frame(self.win_frame, width=514, height=514, highlightbackground='#595959', highlightthickness=2)
        self.embed = tk.Frame(self.pygame_frame, width=512, height=512,)

        # Packing
        self.win_frame.pack(expand=True)
        self.win_frame.pack_propagate(0)

        self.menu.pack(side="left")
        self.menu.pack_propagate(0)
        self.menu_label.pack(ipadx=60, ipady=2)
        self.mute.pack(ipadx=40, ipady=2, pady=5)

        self.pygame_frame.pack(side="left")
        self.embed.pack()

        #This embeds the pygame window
        os.environ['SDL_WINDOWID'] = str(self.embed.winfo_id())
        if platform.system == "Windows":
            os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windib'

        #Start pygame
        pygame.init()
        self.win = pygame.display.set_mode((512, 512))
        self.win.fill(pygame.Color(255, 255, 255))
        pygame.display.init()

        self.root.mainloop()

screen = window()

#Here is sample code that I want to run
pygame.draw.rect(screen.win, (0, 0, 255), (200, 200, 100, 100))
```

When I use `pygame.draw.rect(screen.win, (0, 0, 255), (200, 200, 100, 100))`, nothing happens. Using pygame inside the class worked, but in my more complicated game, using self.variable for all my variables seems unnecessary.

How can I run my code in the pygame window outside of the window class?

Comment: I am checking this. In the meantime - I' just uptated and pushed to Pypi a working set of widgets for pygame - try `pip install pygame-pgu` -  examples and some docs at: https://github.com/parogers/pgu  - maybe you won't need tkinter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embedding a Pygame window into a Tkinter or WxPython frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319059/embedding-a-pygame-window-into-a-tkinter-or-wxpython-frame)

Answer (score 4):

So - besides the obvious missing call to `pygame.display.flip` - which I suppose is what you intended with the call to `pygame.display.init` (`pygame.init` already calls that one) - what I found out is that tkinter needs to initialize its windows and widgets before the packed frame is fully available to be used by Pygame.

I did that by adding a call to `self.root.update_idletasks()` before calling `pygame.init` -- that, and explicitly setting the video driver for my platform (which you already does for Windows), made things work.

Anyway, also, in your code you did not show were you wanted to make the calls to Pygamedrawing functions - as it is, it is well possible that everything is correct, but the code after `screen.window()` is just never run (or rather, just run at program exit) - because you call tkinter.mainloop inside the `__init__` method of your application class.

Moving the call to `mainloop` outside the `__init__` is a good practice, so you can initialize other objects and resources as well - and you actualy do have the `screen` object to operate things on. By making that call inside `__init__` is like your whole program was running "inside the initialization".

In short:

- call `tkinter.update_iddletasks()` before initializing pygame
- remember to call `pygame.display.flip` after you draw anything with Pygame
- arrange your code so that your drawing calls are actually executed, and not blocked after the call to enter tkinter's loop
- You should **seriously** consider using Python 3.7 or later - (the only "python 2" code there is `import Tkinter` which becomes `import tkinter` in Python 3). Python 2 is **really** at the end of line, and there are no updates for projects like pygame on it.
  .

That said, here is your code, modified to run on Linux + Python 3 (should still work on Windows), and to actually perform some actions using the embedded pygame frame.

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import platform
import pygame
import time

class window(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()  # Main window
        self.root.title("SquareScape")
        # self.root.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\17_es\PycharmProjects\square_puzzle\images\icon.ico')
        self.root.configure(background='#9b9b9b')

        # Large Frame
        self.win_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, width=670, height=520, highlightbackground='#595959', highlightthickness=2)

        # menu (left side)
        self.menu = tk.Frame(self.win_frame, width=150, height=516, highlightbackground='#595959', highlightthickness=2)
        self.menu_label = tk.Label(self.menu, text="Settings", bg='#8a8a8a', font=("Courier", "16", "bold roman"))
        self.mute = tk.Button(self.menu, text="XXXX", font="Courier", bg='#bcbcbc', activebackground='#cdcdcd')

        tk.Button(self.menu, text="<->", command=lambda: setattr(self, "direction", (-self.direction[0], self.direction[1]))).pack()
        tk.Button(self.menu, text="^", command=lambda: setattr(self, "direction", (self.direction[0], -self.direction[1]))).pack()

        # pygame
        self.pygame_frame = tk.Frame(self.win_frame, width=514, height=514, highlightbackground='#595959', highlightthickness=2)
        self.embed = tk.Frame(self.pygame_frame, width=512, height=512,)

        # Packing
        self.win_frame.pack(expand=True)
        self.win_frame.pack_propagate(0)

        self.menu.pack(side="left")
        self.menu.pack_propagate(0)
        self.menu_label.pack(ipadx=60, ipady=2)
        self.mute.pack(ipadx=40, ipady=2, pady=5)

        self.pygame_frame.pack(side="left")
        self.embed.pack()
        #This embeds the pygame window
        os.environ['SDL_WINDOWID'] = str(self.embed.winfo_id())
        system = platform.system()
        if system == "Windows":
            os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windib'
        elif system == "Linux":
            os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'x11'

        self.root.update_idletasks()
        #Start pygame
        pygame.init()
        self.win = pygame.display.set_mode((512, 512))

        self.bg_color = (255, 255, 255)
        self.win.fill(self.bg_color)
        self.pos = 0, 0
        self.direction = 10, 10
        self.size = 40
        self.color = (0, 255, 0)
        self.root.after(30, self.update)

        self.root.mainloop()


    def update(self):

        first_move = True
        pygame.draw.rect(self.win, self.bg_color, self.pos + (self.size, self.size))


        self.pos = self.pos[0] + self.direction[0], self.pos[1] + self.direction[1]


        if self.pos[0] < 0 or self.pos[0] > 512 - self.size:
            self.direction = -self.direction[0], self.direction[1]
            self.pos = self.pos[0] + 2 * self.direction[0], self.pos[1] + self.direction[1]
        if self.pos[1] < 0 or self.pos[1] > 512 - self.size:
            self.direction = self.direction[0], -self.direction[1]
            self.pos = self.pos[0] + self.direction[0], self.pos[1] + 2 * self.direction[1]

        pygame.draw.rect(self.win, self.color, self.pos + (self.size, self.size))
        pygame.display.flip()
        self.root.after(30, self.update)


screen = window()
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, I have two questions. First, is there a benefit to calling `pygame.display.flip()` instead of `pygame.display.update()`? Also, when learning about pygame initially, I was told that pygame works a lot better in python 2, is this wrong?

Comment: calling `display.update` should be just as fine. As for working in Python 3, that is wrong nowadays, but was true for a certain period of time when Pygame went almost as an inactive project. Its install in Python 3 was cumbersome, and prone to errors.  The project is healthy and running again, and installs flawlessly with `pip install`.