# Integrate Pygame in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pygame, pysimplegui

I have a game written with a Pygame loop and it currently draws everything happening in the pygame window. I now want to integrate this window into a larger PySimpleGUI window to have nice functionality around the game. Is this possible?

I tried to use the code from [here](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_PyGame_Integration.py). The problem is that I get an error like this which comes from VIDEODRIVER at line 25:

```
pygame.error: windib not available
```

I changed this to 'windows' but then the Pygame window is separated from the PySimpleGUI as a different window.

Can I make the pygame loop as a window INSIDE the PySimpleGUI? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the detached window is an [open, unresolved issue with pygame 2](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/1574).

If you're able to downgrade to pygame 1.9.6, the [linked demo](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_PyGame_Integration.py) works as expected on Windows after changing the line 25 to:
`os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windows'` as described.

Answer (score 0):

As said [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319059/embedding-a-pygame-window-into-a-tkinter-or-wxpython-frame),

This line only work on windows:

```
os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windib'
```

So make a code to skip it when the os is not Windows.

```
import platform
if platform.system == "Windows":
    os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windib'
```